# How to copy a map to another map

Tags: java, dictionary

I have two maps

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, List<String>> newMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

in `map` my key is a user age. I want to group them by age and to copy to the `newMap`. For instance: all ages under 10 to 1 group (and to copy all values to one list) and all older 10 and under 20 to another etc.
here is what I have tried to do

```
for (int m = 10; m <= 80; m += 10) {                            
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();
        int age = Integer.parseInt(key);
        if (age <= m) {                     
            if ((value = newMap.get(m)) != null) {
                value.addAll(map.get(key));
                newMap.put(m, value);                           
            } else {
                newMap.put(m, value);

            }
        } else continue;            
    }
}
```

But I got ages as a key and null as a values `[10 = null; 30 = null 20 = null; ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just iterate the `entrySet()`?

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    // Since integer division is used, we'll lose the "ones" digit
    Integer newKey = Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey()) / 10 * 10;

    List<String> value = newMap.get(newKey) {
    if (value == null) {
        value = new LinkedList<>();
        newMap.put(newKey, value);
    }
    value.addAll(entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Mureinik's answer is better, but to give something more closely resembling what you originally wrote:

```
for (int m = 10; m <= 80; m += 10) {
    List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        int age = Integer.parseInt(key);

        if (age < m && age >= m - 9) {
            value.addAll(map.get(key));
        }
    }

    newMap.put(m, value);
}
```